# isEnum() ambiguous behaviour for anonymous inner class

Tags: java, enums

As per my understanding, `Class.isEnum()` should return true for any enum value declared using the `enum` statement.

If the enum is declared anonymously, it returns false.

The documentation for `isEnum()` states this:

> "Returns true if and only if this class was declared as an enum in
>   the source code."

This seems bit ambiguous to me.

I'm looking for is a way to distinguish enum constants from other objects, so I need `isEnum()` to return true for all enum constants, even if they anonymously override something.

Is there any way to identify enum constants, apart from this?

**Run the class and look at the results of `isEnum()` for each constant. It will print out the value of `isEnum()` for each constant.**

I was expecting all constants should return true for `isEnum()`.
But sadly The third constant returns false for `isEnum()`.

```
public enum EnumTest {
Alpha(3), Beta(6), Delta(4) {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Gamma";
    }
},
Epsilon(9);

private int value;

EnumTest(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public static boolean isEnumWorkaround(Class enumClass) {
    while (enumClass.isAnonymousClass()) {
        enumClass = enumClass.getSuperclass();
    }
    return enumClass.isEnum();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (EnumTest thing : EnumTest.values()) {
        String nameString = thing + " (" + thing.name() + ")";
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "%-18s isEnum = %-5b [workaround isEnum = %b]", nameString, thing
                        .getClass().isEnum(), isEnumWorkaround(thing.getClass())));
    }
  }
}
```

Please check and let me know if my understanding is right or not.

Comment: Would just doing `object instanceof Enum` work for you?

Comment: Java is strongly typed, though...you should *know* if you're messing with an enum...

Comment: Or would `Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())` work ? (In case that you have Classes rather than instances)

Comment: @Erwin That would be good idea let me try that too;

Comment: @Makoto - I am not messing with enum friend i am just going with the rules.

Comment: The feature is working as designed. You may want it to do something different, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, `Class#isEnum()` is not aimed for you to check whether a class is-an enum.  It simply allow you to introspect the class declaration.

As mentioned in comment, what you want to do is easily achievable by

```
yourEnumValue.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Enum.class)
```

or

```
yourEnumValue instanceof Enum
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian  don't you think java documentation must be changed for this.

Comment: I think it has already clearly stated that "Returns true if and only if **this** class was **declared as an enum** in the source code".  There are a lot of similar cases for what is provided through reflection.  For example, iirc, if you `getDeclaredMethods()`, it is not going to include what is inherited from its superclass.  `isEnum()` is by similar argument only let you introspect the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, you need your `enumWorkaround` to check whether the third value is an enum. Check the code of `isEnum`:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Class.java#Class.isEnum%28%29

It checks for the enum bit **and** the super class. This means that your `enumWorkaround` might still fail if you hava a concrete class that does not directly inherit from `java.lang.Enum`, but I guess that is impossible for enum constants...

Comment: Yeah...agreed it might fail too...:( searching for best alternative ..It would be great if you can share your thoughts on what would be the best option for me –